# Как можно связать ключевое слово с функцией?

Tags: javascript

Имеется **массив** состоящий из ключевых слов`["left", "right", "top", "bottom"]`

Имеются **функции** которые должны быть связаны с данными элементами 
массива.

Например:

`function flipLeft () { /* some code */ } 
 function flipBottom () { /* some code */ }`

И так далее.

Предполагается что эти функции будут вызываться последовательно согласно тому как они размещены в массиве, к слову, в массиве ключевые слова могут быть в произвольном порядке:

`["right", "left", "bottom", "top"]`

Вопрос в следующем, каким образом можно связать эти ключевые слова с конкретными функциями ?

Например: **left => flipLeft()**

Другими словами если передано **left** вызвать **flipLeft()** и аналогично с другими функциями.

**P.S** 
У меня есть решение но оно не совсем мне подходит, хотелось бы посмотреть другие варианты.
Спасибо

Comment: "У меня есть решение но оно не совсем мне подходит" - ??

Answer (score 5):

Можно через объявление внутри свойств и вызов их.

```js
var obj = {
  left: function flipLeft() {
    console.log("flipLeft");
  },
  right: function flipRight() {
    console.log("flipRight");
  },
   bottom: function flipBottom() {
    console.log("flipBottom");
  },
  top:function fliptop() {
    console.log("fliptop");
  },
};

for(var key in obj){
  obj[key]();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно с помощью eval, но лично я бы сделал просто switch/case, где ключ каждого кейса это название функции, а тело - это вызов нужной.

```
switch(funcName)
{
    case "right":
       flipRight();
    break;
    case "left":
        flipLeft();
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

UPDATE

Кстати, автоматический вызов функции через eval или другое что-то похожее - это зло! (мое мнение конечно). Замечательный способ выстрелить себе в ногу нечаянно расслабившись :)) Так что свич или подобный механизм - самое то! Только не забудте прописать кейс по умолчанию (default) от греха подальше.

Answer (score 3):

```js
let arr = ["left", "right", "top", "bottom", "left", "right"];

let funcMap = {
  left: flipLeft,
  right: flipRight,
  top: flipTop,
  bottom: flipBottom
};

function flipLeft() {
  console.log('←')
}

function flipBottom() {
  console.log('↓')
}

function flipRight() {
  console.log('→')
}

function flipTop() {
  console.log('↑')
}

arr.forEach(item => funcMap[item]());
```

Comment: То что нужно! {{ thumbs up }}

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант вызывать функции через `window`, и чтобы избежать лишней награможденности кода, можно изменить элементы массива, чтобы они начинались с большой буквы, если это возможно.

```js
let array = ["left", "right", "top", "bottom"];

for (let item of array) {
  runFunction(item);
}

function runFunction(element) {
  window['flip' + element.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + element.slice(1)]();
  //window['flip'+element](); //можно записать так, если элементы в массиве будут с большой буквы
}

function flipLeft() {
  alert('left');
};

function flipBottom() {
  alert('Bottom');
};

function flipTop() {
  alert('Top');
};

function flipRight() {
  alert('right');
};
```

Comment: А если объекта `window` не существует? Отнюдь не факт, что автору вопроса нужен код именно для браузерного JS.

Comment: Ну, в таком случае, можно создать свой объект, в котором будут эти функции включены (По сути это отражено у Вас в ответе).

Answer (score 0):

```
function firstFunc () { ... }
function secondFunc () { ... }
function thirdFunc () { ... }

['first', 'third', 'second', 'first'].forEach(funcName => eval(`${funcName}Func()`))
```